# Why is my BootstrapSwitch not working in a Backbone table built using a foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I'm trying to replace a checkbox in a table with this good looking bootstrap switch.

I'm also using Backbone.marionette.js and the binding handler as suggested by this link http://www.jque.re/plugins/version3/bootstrap.switch/.

However I cannot get the binding handler to work and or the switch to be clickable in the table built using a backbone for each.

Answer (score 0):

I have just add simple code in onShow() method in backbone view side . It seems work for that

My HTML code

```
 <td style="text-align:center">
      <div class="make-switch">
         <input class="userEnable" type="checkbox" checked>
      </div>
    </td>
```

My Backbone code

```
 List.Users = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    -----
    -----
      onShow: function() {
            $('.userEnable').wrap('<div class="make-switch">').parent().bootstrapSwitch();
            }
    }
```